# Django app for geolocation (more then country)

Tags: python, django, geolocation

I'm looking for some kind of app/tools/something to location of an IP adress.
For now, I have simple code to 'catch' country name from IP.
I'm using GeoIP and diplomat

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
from diplomat.models import ISOCountry

def get_country(ip):
    countries = dict(
    [(country.alpha2, country) for country in ISOCountry.objects.all()])
    g = GeoIP()
    code = g.country(ip)["country_code"]
    return countries.get(code)
```

And I get pycountry (which is used later in highcharts map, so this data(county,state,city), can't be just a string, I think)

But now I need more information, like state (in US, Germany, etc), city

Have you guys have any idea? This can be a paid tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GeoIP.city`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/#django.contrib.gis.geoip.GeoIP.city) to get the information of a city for an IP.

> Returns a dictionary of city information for the given query. Some of
>   the values in the dictionary may be undefined (`None`).

The `GeoIP` library uses values from the [MaxMind datasets.](http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/) If it is able to find the value for a particular field, it will return that value otherwise it returns `None`. If in some fields, you are getting `None`, it means the dataset does not contain the value for that particular field.

**For [example:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/#example)**

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
>>> g = GeoIP()
>>> g.city('72.14.207.99') # pass the IP to get the city information
{'area_code': 650,
'city': 'Mountain View',
'country_code': 'US',
'country_code3': 'USA',
'country_name': 'United States',
'dma_code': 807,
'latitude': 37.419200897216797,
'longitude': -122.05740356445312,
'postal_code': '94043',
'region': 'CA'}
```

Comment: The `GeoIP` library uses the [MaxMind datasets](http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/). The library returns the city information using the values stored in the database. If the value is found for a particular field in the database, then it returns the value otherwise it returns `None`. Since `None` was returned in your case, it means it could not find the `region` from the database for the given IP. There was no value stored in the `region` field in the Maxmind dataset for that IP.

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful?  Seems to be close to what you want, no?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/